# What does it mean to pass `_` (i.e., underscore) as the sole parameter to a Dart language function?

Tags: syntax, dart

I'm learning Dart and see the following idiom a lot:

`someFuture.then((_) => someFunc());`

I have also seen code like:

`someOtherFuture.then(() => someOtherFunc());`

Is there a functional difference between these two examples?
A.k.a., What does passing `_` as a parameter to a Dart function do?

This is particularly confusing given Dart's use of `_` as a prefix for declaring private functions.

Comment: The `then(() => ...` would be a bug. :)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It's a variable named `_` typically because you plan to not use it and throw it away. For example you can use the name `x` or `foo` instead.
The difference between `(_)` and `()` is simple in that one function takes an argument and the other doesn't.

> **DON’T use a leading underscore for identifiers that aren’t private.**
>
> **Exception:** An unused parameter can be named _, __, ___, etc. This
> happens in things like callbacks where you are passed a value but you
> don’t need to use it. Giving it a name that consists solely of
> underscores is the idiomatic way to indicate the value isn’t used.

https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style

Comment: So, the function being called expects a parameter, and the code is passing junk (an unassigned variable)? Why not use `null`, for clarity? Just to save typing? And, won't the function be a little surprised when it tries to use the unassigned, untyped variable? Or, am I missing something?

Comment: 1) It's not passing junk, it's just not being used.
2) `null` is a keyword and can't be used as a variable name.
3) Yes, It saves typing and also gives a low profile look.
4) No, `_` is an assigned variable. No surprises here.

Comment: I learned something new today. Thank you. The thing that makes the new learners (in Dart) like me confuse is that it is a kind of the same 'convention' used for the private properties.

Comment: I am looking at Dart, and think the language designers' decision to use convention rather than impose syntax for things such as member visibility is awful. "Convention" is like "Lore", surviving through gossip and not structure. I also think the "preferred" use of single-quotes is deplorable, but that's for a different thread.

Comment: @Joseph, at some point structure ends and convention takes over for every language. The only way to have it your way is to make your own language and grow your own community and become the BDFL. glhf

Comment: @Zectobumo - of course, but you make too broad a stroke. Ignoring decades of "private" and "public" for the guesswork of "_" is negligent.

Answer (score 8):

An underscore (`_`) is usually an indication that you will not be using this parameter within the block. This is just a neat way to write code.

Let's say I've a method with two parameters `useful` and `useless` and I'm not using `useless` in the code block:

```
void method(int useful, int useless) {
  print(useful);
}
```

Since `useless` variable won't be used, I should rather write the above code as:

```
void method(int useful, int _) { // 'useless' is replaced with '_'
  print(useful);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

From the Dart Doc - [PREFER using `_`, `__`, etc. for unused callback parameters.](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style#prefer-using-_-__-etc-for-unused-callback-parameters)

> Sometimes the type signature of a callback function requires a
> parameter, but the callback implementation doesn't *use* the
> parameter. In this case, it's idiomatic to name the unused parameter
> `_`. If the function has multiple unused parameters, use additional
> underscores to avoid name collisions: `__`, `___`, etc.
>
> ```dart
> futureOfVoid.then((_) {
>   print('Operation complete.');
> });
> ```
>
> This guideline is only for functions that are both *anonymous and
> local*. These functions are usually used immediately in a context
> where it's clear what the unused parameter represents. In contrast,
> top-level functions and method declarations don't have that context,
> so their parameters must be named so that it's clear what each
> parameter is for, even if it isn't used.

Copy paste the following code in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev) and hit Run -

```dart
void main() {
  
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
    print("No argument Anonymous function");
  });
  
  funcReturnsInteger().then((_) {
    print("Single argument Anonymous function " + 
    "stating not interested in using argument " +
    "but can be accessed like this -> $_");
  });
}

Future<int> funcReturnsInteger() async {
  return 100;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That expression is similar to "callbacks" in node.js, the expression have relation to async task.

First remember that `=> expr` expression is shorthand for `{return *expr*}`, now in `someFuture.then((_) => someFunc())`, `someFuture` is a variable of type `Future`, and this keeps your async task, with the `.then` method you tell what to do with your async task (once completed), and args in this method you put the callback `((response) => doSomethingWith(response))`.

You learn more at [Future-Based APIs](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/futures/) and [Functions in Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch02.html#functions). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Very common use, is when we need to push a new route with Navigator but the context variable in the builder is not going to be used:

```
// context is going to be used
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (context) => NewPage(),
));


// context is NOT going to be used
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (_) => NewPage(),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what people are confusing here is that many think the `_`  in

```
someFuture.then((_) => someFunc());
```

is a parameter provided to the callback function which is wrong, its actually a parameter passed back from the function that you can give a name that you want (except reserved keywords of course), in this case its an underscore to show that the parameter will not be used. otherwise, you could do something like in example given above:`((response) => doSomethingWith(response))`