# Is there a linter rule for enforcing underscore parameter names in anonymous functions if they are not used in Dart?

Tags: dart

I am coming from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25517016/what-does-it-mean-to-pass-i-e-underscore-as-the-sole-parameter-to-a-dart).

"Effective Dart: Style" documentation also suggests to use underscore as parameter names in an anonymous function [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style#prefer-using-_-__-etc-for-unused-callback-parameters).

Is there a linter rule for this to put in `analysis_options.yaml` to enforce it?